# why dropdown is not binding when its in ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Part2ctrl">
    <form novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="SaveData()">
        <input type="text" name="tname" ng-model="tab1.Name" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />
        <br/> CountryName <select ng-model="CountryID" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-change="GetStatesd()"></select> StateName
        <select ng-model="StateID" ng-options="I.StateID as I.StateName for I in StateList"></select><input type="submit" value="{{SubmitText}}" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("Part2ctrl", function($scope, Revservedata) {
    $scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function(dee) {
        $scope.isFormValid = dee;
    }) $scope.SaveData = function(data) {
        if ($scope.SubmitText == "Save") {
            $scope.meassage = '';
            $scope.isFormValid = true;
            if ($scope.isFormValid) {
                $scope.SubmitText = "please wait....";
                Revservedata.SaveFormData($scope.tab1).then(function(d) {
                    alert(d);
                    if (d == "Sucess") {
                        cleardata();
                    }
                }) Revservedata.GetCountry().then(function(d) {
                    $scope.CountryList = d.data;
                }) $scope.GetStatesd = function(CountryID) {
                    Revservedata.GetStates($scope.CountryID).then(function(d) {
                        $scope.StateList = d.data;
                    })
                }
            }
        });
}).factory("Revservedata", function($http, $q) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetCountry = function() {
        return $http.get("/Home/GetCountry");
    }
    fac.GetStates = function(CountryID) {
        return $http.get("/Home/GetStates?CountryID=" + CountryID)
    }
    fac.SaveFormData = function(data) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: "/Home/Create",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            header: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }) return defer.promise;
    }
    return fac;
})
```

Comment: when dropdown is out from $scope.Savedat()then its loaded perfectly

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)